# Complicated 2-cell diagrams

Tags: xy-pic

I would very much like to typeset the diagrams below, but I am absolutely unable to understand how to do this from any of the xypic guides.
Help and examples greatly appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Is your problem solved by the answer below? If yes, please consider to [accept](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) it in order to close this post. If not, please tell us, what is missing.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi I can't speak for the OP, but he asks specifically for an xypic solution. "Use a different program" may be a fine solution from a technical standpoint (and appears ubiquitously on this site) but it doesn't answer the question as written above, and in general learning a whole new syntax for one trick when you're already familiar with another is a hassle most mathematicians want to avoid.

Answer (score 5):

My usual recommendation these days is to switch to a more modern package. Here's the last one with [`tikz-cd`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz-cd):

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,mathtools}
\tikzset{mydescription/.style={anchor=center,fill=white}}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}
  \mathcal{C} \ar[rr,bend left=55,"F"{name=F}] 
              \ar[rr,bend left=20,"G"{name=G,mydescription}]
              \ar[rr,bend right=20,"H"{name=H,mydescription}]
              \ar[rd,bend right=30,"K"{swap}] & & 
    \mathcal{E} \\
  & \mathcal{D} \ar[ru,bend right=30,"\operatorname{Ran}_K H"{swap}]
                \ar[Rightarrow,to=H,"\epsilon^H"{swap}] &
  \ar[Rightarrow,from=H,to=G,"\beta"{swap}]
  \ar[Rightarrow,from=G,to=F,"\alpha"{swap,pos=0.3},shorten >=1.5pt]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If `Ran` is a common operator in your document, you'll of course want to define it globally with `\DeclareMathOperator` instead of the *ad hoc* `\operatorname` I've used in the code here.